# how to use war in a maven based project

Tags: maven, war, pom.xml

I want to use a war file in my project. Do you think I can do that in a maven based project? I should write or define something at pom.xml in order to do that?

It is possible to add an external jar to pom.xml . But is it possible to add an external war to pom.xml and use its classes such like we use jar as a library ???

Comment: This question is much too broad. Provide an example project (or two, one for the WAR), and describe exactly, what you want to achieve and what you already have tried.

Comment: I have one java based spring maven project. And I want to use a same java based spring maven based project inside my project. I want to use some classes of it. Do you think I should do something in pom.xm?. I guess it is well described

Comment: You may guess so. I don't think so. Others may not think so as well. I only tried to show you a way how you may get better support. Take it or leave it :-)

Comment: it is possible to add an external jar to pom.xml . But is it possible to add an external war to pom.xml and use its classes such like we use jar as a library ???

Comment: The question is definitely better now. One question mark would have been enough though ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't whether it is possible from the technical side, but I would avoid it. Instead, put the classes you want to reuse into a jar project and reference that jar from all your war projects.

Answer (score -1):

```
 type
```

element can be used to provide dependency type and classes can be used.

```
     <xs:element name="type" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string" default="jar">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation source="version">4.0.0</xs:documentation>
      <xs:documentation source="description">
        The type of dependency. This defaults to jar. While it usually represents the extension on
        the filename of the dependency, that is not always the case. A type can be mapped to a different
        extension and a classifier.
        The type often correspongs to the packaging used, though this is also not always the case.
        Some examples are jar, war, ejb-client and test-jar.
        New types can be defined by plugins that set
        extensions to true, so this is not a complete list.
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
```

example:

```
    <dependency>
         <groupId>project-group</groupId>
        <artifactId>war-artifact</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Because you do not answer the question: You only say that it is possible to reference war, not if it is possible to use classes from that war as if it were a jar.